# Apache vhost privilege separation using mod_selinux

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, httpd, selinux, nextcloud

I have 2 *sites/apps* on a server; a proprietary app, and Nextcloud. Nextcloud will be using the `files_external` storage plugin which allows for *local* mounts, but I do **NOT** want it to be able to browse and view the source of the proprietary app... thus `mod_selinux` and sedomain children.

I'm using `mod_selinux` to create domain children, and I'm assigning a child id to each of the sites and labelling their respective app and data directories accordingly in their vhost definitions...

**httpd.conf**

```
selinuxServerDomain *:s0-s0:c0.c100
```

**proprietary.vhost.conf**

```
selinuxDomainVal *:s0:c10
```

**nextcloud.vhost.conf**

```
selinuxDomainVal *:s0:c20
```

The app directory, where the code is located has the following permissions and contexts applied...

```
drwxr-x---.  4 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0:c10 4096 Jan 17 17:02 proprietary_app_dir
drwxr-x---. 15 apache apache unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0:c20 4096 Jan 20 08:09 nextcloud
```

**The problem...**
Everything is running, but the problem is, I can still browse the proprietary app folder using nextcloud even though the proprietary app's directory has a domain context limited to `s0:c10`, and as far as the vhost is defined, Nextcloud *should* be running as `s0:c20`.

I know that SELinux is doing it's job because I can't view folders like /etc even though *other* users have read permissions on it, I can only view folders with contexts of `httpd_sys_(rw_)content_t` as it should be.

I would have expected that a child process of `c20` should not be able to read a folder asking for `c10`.  So the only thing I can think of is that the spawned children of `httpd_t` (via `mod_selinux`) are not using the `selinuxDomainVal` contexts that I've defined in the vhost files.

I'm not sure what I've done wrong, have I misconfigured this somehow, or have I forgotten a step?  Would appreciate any help you can offer.

Extra info...

- CentOS8
- Apache 2.4.37
- PHP 7.3 (via remi)
- PHP-FPM
- mod_selinux (repackaged RPM from fedora 31)

Answer (score 0):

Nextcloud is a PHP-based software, not sure how your proprietary one works (maybe also PHP?). The actual directory browsing in Nextcloud happens using PHP, in your case using PHP-FPM from what I get. I would assume that you're either using the same PHP-FPM pool for both VHosts or that the PHP-FPM SELinux context is the same across both pools. Even my assumption might be wrong, you should provide also details here regarding your PHP configuration and what you did (or didn't do) regarding SELinux.